# how can a wordpress wesite show the visitor's name when he visit the website ? like welcome <visitor name>>

Tags: wordpress

If someone visit my website then how can I show them their name when they visit and show them a welcome message like welcome Atul. My website is created in WordPress.

Comment: What you want actualy requires users to be registered and logged in in your website...

Answer (score 0):

Your visitor need to be registered on your website. This is the only way WordPress can find his information. To know more about displaying information of USER read this article "http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo"

Answer (score 0):

To allow this to happen the user of the site will have to be registered as otherwise there is not a method to find their name. When they are logged in by default it will say something like "Welcome, Woolnut". There are some small plugins that can change the welcome message for you but you will need to get the user to log in before you have access to name for them. If they are logged in already and you want to display their username / name then take at look at [this >>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) link, it may be of use!

**Edit**

Turns out my link is the same one as the other answer! (Is probably the best link however...)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better way is to call [wp_get_current_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) instead, like so:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 !== $user->ID ) {
    echo $user->display_name;
}
```

This is a wrapper for the get_currentuserinfo that actually returns the user to you directly instead of just setting a global variable. It returns a WP_User object with the information of the current user in it.

If the user is unknown or not logged in, then the function will return a WP_User with the ID set to zero, so you can check for that and also handle unknown users.